# Dúvidas com link âncora

Tags: javascript, html

Criei um script da seguinte forma:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#mostrar_planos').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top}, 500,'swing');
  });
});
</script>

<a href="#mostrar_planos" id="mostrar_planos">Confira os planos</a>

<section id="mostrar_planos"> conteudo </section>
```

Ele funciona normalmente, porém não deixa a ID que foi chamada, no caso o `section`, na parte superior da tela.

Ele fica no meio da tela. Existe alguma forma de ajustar isso?

Preciso que quando clique no link, ele deslize a página e deixe esse `section` no topo da página, não no meio.

Comment: Cara não utiliza **bind** foi descontinuado o uso, utilize **on** no lugar e se precisar **off** ao invés de **unbind**. Leia mais na API do jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/?s=bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara seu problema é que vc está usando no link o mesmo `ID` que está usando no conteúdo para o qual vc quer ir.

Repare que não seu conteúdo tem um `ID` igual, repetido, com o mesmo nome do `ID` do link: `id="mostrar_planos"` Basta tirar o ID do link que resolve.

```
<a href="#mostrar_planos" id="mostrar_planos">Confira os planos</a>

<section id="mostrar_planos"> conteudo </section>
```

**OBS:** Se não houver conteúdo restante abaixo do elemento que vc a ancora a tela vai parar de subir. Veja no código abaixo, eu coloquei um offset para o conteúdo para a 50px do topo, e abaixo dele uma div com 500px de altura. Se vc testar em uma janela pequena ele fica certinho. Mas se a janela tiver mais de 500px de altura o elemento não sobe mais. Logo se no seu caso não houver mais nada abaixo do elemento ancorado ele vai para antes do topo.

Veja funcionando.

```js
$('a.teste').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),
    targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;


    $('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: targetOffset - 50 //altura que para antes do topo da tela
    }, 500,'swing');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<a class="teste" title="segmentos" href="#mostrar_planos">Confira os planos</a>
        
<DIV style="height: 200vh;"></DIV>

<section id="mostrar_planos"> conteudo </section>

<DIV style="height: 500px; background:tomato;"> div com 500px de altura</DIV>
```

Comment: Realmente, mas mesmo assim não consegui ajustar a posição que deve parar o section, quando desliza. Tem como ajustar isso?

Comment: @Wendler cara editei minha resposta. Leia a **OBS** que fiz e execute o código que atualizei para entender melhor em uma janela pequena e depois na tela inteira. Qq coisa me fala

Comment: Tem como colocar esse espaço para aparecer somente quando clicar no anchor? Se eu colocar direto na página vai ficar estranho.

Comment: Cara deve tar sim, eu particularmente não vou saber te responder pq não entendo muito de JS. Se essa for sua intenção te recomendo a marcar essa questão como resolvida `✓` se ela respondeu esse problema, e abrir uma outra perguntando sobre essa sua nova dúvida. Alguém que entende mais de JS vai saber te responder. Mas acho que a lógica é pegar a altura do elemento ancorado, subtrair da altura da tela e colocar esse valor como margin-bottom algo assim...